# Nonbonded interactions on the GPU

Tags: python, gromacs

i'm using this command

```
gmx mdrun -deffnm nvt0 -nb gpu
```

but got

```
Nonbonded interactions on the GPU were requested with -nb gpu, but the GROMACS
binary has been built without GPU support. Either run without selecting GPU
options or recompile GROMACS with GPU support enabled
```

I've Nvidia rtx2060 with cuda 11.1 on ubnutu 18.4.5

Comment: I don't know gromacs but that would be normal for GPU in ML, CPU and GPU uses two different compilations.

Comment: Someone (with the same GPU) asked the same question during the weekend that they have now deleted, where I said about CUDA and cmake with `-DGMX_GPU=ON`. If this was you, please do not do this as you are wasting volunteers' time —and I believe may get you blocked (maybe?). A lesser evil is to edit the Q to bump it.

Comment: I've put a post on the Meta forum https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251/duplicate-ops-and-op-deletion-of-response-postings

Comment: Try here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/. There's an entire GROMACS tag there with way more questions.

Answer (score 4):

As the error tells you: `the GROMACS binary has been built without GPU support`.
Did you install gromacs with `apt-get`? Usually these kind of programs are shipped with a `basic` built, with a lot of features disabled.
If you did built gromacs from source, then cuda was not found during configuration.
I would try building gromacs from source and:

1. be sure cuda is in your path and check that `nvcc` and the drivers have a matching version
2. run cmake and check the output, to see if the video card is recognised
3. run cmake with `-DGMX_GPU=ON`

Note that it seems that gromacs doesn't support multiple gpu accelerations( e.g. it is either `openCL` or `cuda`, you can't have both)

Comment: thanks for helping . i did it already used this command -DGMX_GPU=ON but still got error . i'm now removing gromacs and will install it from scratch taking your answer in my consideration and will get back .. thanks again

Comment: @user5520049 When you have time, please note whether you were able to finish compiler with `-DGMX_GPU=ON`, noting that you would need to still copy the resulting recompiled binary to somewhere in your $PATH.

Comment: This was a great answer fra! We have a [few unanswered GROMACS questions here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gromacs?tab=Unanswered), are you able to help us out at all with those? I'm trying to help take care of the unanswered queue.